# Send files from remote server to a pod (Kubernetes ?)

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I am having a minikube cluster and pod running in it.I need to send a file from a remote server to the pod. How to do it.?
Is it possible using persistent volume?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For the most part Kubernetes volumes aren't accessible from outside the cluster, but any other way you'd send a file to a process (for example, via HTTP POST) should work fine.